# How to force CMake to fail on first error

Tags: cmake

I have a "long to build" target with many dependencies. In order to build the final executable, I need to make some checks. If those are failing, then I want to avoid building the long target. So I did:

```
add_custom_target(LongTarget)
add_custom_command(TARGET LongTarget
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "BUILDING LongTarget")

add_custom_target(FinalTarget)
add_dependencies(FinalTarget LongTarget)
add_custom_command(TARGET FinalTarget PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND "CHECKS_FAIL")
add_custom_command(TARGET FinalTarget POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "BUILDING FinalTarget")
```

But LongTarget is built first, and checks fail **only after**. It seems this is because PRE_BUILD flag is not well-supported on VS (at least).

So I tried:

```
add_custom_target(LongTarget)
add_custom_command(TARGET LongTarget
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "BUILDING LongTarget")

add_custom_target(ChecksTarget)
add_custom_command(TARGET ChecksTarget COMMAND "CHECKS_FAIL")

add_custom_target(FinalTarget)
add_dependencies(FinalTarget ChecksTarget LongTarget)
add_custom_command(TARGET FinalTarget POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "BUILDING FinalTarget")
```

Now, checks are ran first (and fail), but LongTarget is built anyways. So I would like to abort building as soon as an error in encountered.

Comment: In both scripts **nothing** prevents `LongTarget` to be built. `PRE_BUILD` step for `FinalTarget` is executed only after all target's *dependencies* is built, so build sequence should be `LongTarget`-`PRE_BUILD`-`FinalTarget`. In the second script the target `ChecksTarget` is at the "same level" as `LongTarget`, so these targets can be built in any order. If you want `CheckTarget` to be built before `LongTarget`, then add dependency between them: `add_dependencies(LongTarget CheckTarget)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: thanks for your answer. But I do not want LongTarget to depend upon ChecksTarget actually. Only when I build FinalTarget. But LongTarget should be buildable "as-is".

Comment: The only way for force some order between commands and targets is specifying proper dependencies. If the target `LongTarget` doesn't depend from anything, then nothing prevents it from building first, before the checks.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: actually, it seems (if I am not mistaken) that this will not work either. Because even though dependencies fail, the current target will still try to build. So, yes, you can enforce order, but this will not be enough.

Comment: If any of a target's dependency fails to build, then the target won't be built at all. "Fails to build" means that some build action returns an error code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: are you sure about that? When I execute this cmake (https://pastebin.com/0NXZYHqn) , it shows that it is actually building all 3 targets. I am using VS.

Comment: In the referenced script you incorrectly add "CHECKS_FAIL" command - signature `add_custom_command(TARGET)` **requires** one of `PRE_BUILD`, `PRE_LINK` or `POST_BUILD` keywords. It looks strange that CMake doesn't warn about incorrect command.

Comment: While the doc says so, it seems it is not mandatory. I am getting no warning using CMake 3.13.1. But even when fixing this, it still the same result. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: "But even when fixing this" - How **exactly** do you fix it? (Which keyword do you use?). And what is a execution sequence do you observe? (Which targets are built and in which order?).

Comment: I just added PRE_BUILD to the add_custom_command. I build FinalTarget, ChecksTarget fails, but LongTarget and FinalTarget are build. I see, in order CHECKS_FAIL, BUILDING LongTarget then BUILDING FinalTarget.

Comment: Hm, this is really weird. In the past, Visual Studio had [some problems](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-April/028915.html) with fails on `POST_BUILD` step not propagated to the target. May be, your case is somehow related with that. BTW, `PRE_BUILD` step is useful when your custom *command* produces some files, which are needed for the target. Otherwise, **custom target** looks more preferable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I indeed tested this on Xcode and it works as expected. Could it be related to parallel builds being ran?

Comment: I don't know. [The problem](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-April/028915.html) in Visual Studio which I referred above is about ignoring a result of `POST_BUILD` step completely.